# non-trivial conditions for integrability of $ | d^2u/ dr d\theta | $ on an annulus

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $u \in C^\infty (A)$ be a smooth bounded function on annulus $A = \{ (r,\theta) | \varepsilon \le r < 1 \}$, converging to a continuous function on the outer boundary (smooth on the inner).

I am searching for conditions I can impose on $u$ such that the following integral converges:
$ \int\limits_\varepsilon^1 \mathrm{d}r \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta |\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 u(r,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta}|$

Possible directions: The functions I am interested have a bounded number of extrema, seen as functions of $\theta$ for each fixed $r$, and perhaps said extrema could be fixed to lie on rays from the origin. Additional conditions are welcome.

It is probably obvious but I am not interested in just the condition e.g. 
the derivative in the integral is bounded" or simiar.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks, the mistake was due to an edit. I wanted to make the problem more general. I corrected it now to what it should really be - an annulus closed from inside and open from outside, so that the function is smooth on the inside and there are no integrability problems there.

Comment: It's not clear what sort of criteria would satisfy you. Could you elaborate more on what you are looking for? I don't see your extrema condition as being helpful. In fact, it is difficult (but not impossible) to find functions that don't have a bounded number of extrema, at least if you are willing to count a constant interval as a single extremum. One possible approach would be to start with the requirement that $$\lim_{r\to 1} (1 -r)\left|\frac{d^2u}{drd\theta}\right| = 0$$, then see what requirements on $u$ itself would guarantee this.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks for the tip. I haven't thought to do that so it is at least  a direction, but I don't expect it will be very helpful as the condition is still on the integrand. If it helps any, for each fixed $r$, $u(r,\theta)$ is the radial coordinate of a simple curve $u,\theta$ enclosing a convex domain.